# NestJS Typescript extend multiple classes

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, nestjs

I'm trying to extend multiple classes for one class. My code is like that:

```
export class UserInitialParams {
  @ApiProperty({example: 'john@doe.com', description: 'Email'})
  @Prop({required: true})
  email: string;

  @ApiProperty({example: 'admin', description: 'Role'})
  @Prop({required: true, default: 'admin'})
  role: string;
}

export class UserRegisterParams extends UserInitialParams{
  @ApiProperty({example: 'asd123456', description: 'Password'})
  @Prop({required: true})
  password: string;
}

@Schema({timestamps: true})
export class Common {
    @Prop({ required: false, default: null })
    deletedAt: Date | null;

    @Prop({ required: false, default: false })
    isDeleted: boolean | null;

    softDelete: Function;
    unDelete: Function;
    isOwner: Function;

    constructor() {
        this.deletedAt = null;
        this.isDeleted = false;
    }
}
```

And I want to extend new class (`User`) with both `UserRegisterParams` and `Common` classes and it should do something like that:

```
export class User extends UserRegisterParams, Common {}
```

I want to use all properties and methods in these classes.

I couldn't figure it out. How can I do this?

Comment: does [IntersectionType()](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types#intersection) satisfies your needs?

Comment: You can only extend one class but you can Implement an arbitrary number of types, including class types. However, that's probably not what you're looking for here since you want to inherit the decorators that are apply to the members of two different classes.